# Linq Join Error: The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Tags: c#, mongodb

This is the code i've tried to join two collections its not working please help

```
var query = from p in collection.AsQueryable()  
            join o in collection1 
               on p.tag_description equals o.key into joined 
            from sub_o in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { p.tag_id, sub_o.record_hour };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have two different datatype's variable in `On Clause`.

You need to make it same. This is the sample code for that

```
 on new { Description= p.tag_description } equals new { Description= (string)o.key }
```

Comment: Thanks! That's not working now i've tried this ..                                          
    var query2 = collection2.Aggregate()
                               .Lookup("opc_tags", "tag_id", "tag_id", "result");                        Still its now working :( please help!